# Warning: string is not a string literal(potentially insecure) for code

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a beginner in iOS, can some one help me:
I am getting warning: `string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)` for below code

```
-( void )gettingEntitySchemaForGivenKayValueFromDataBase:( RequestType )requestType ParamDict:( NSDictionary * )parameterDict
    {
        PersistenceFromDataBase *persistanceDataObj=[ PersistenceFromDataBase sharedInstance ];
        //[ NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[ persistanceDataObj getEntitySchemaForGinvenEntityIs:parameterDict ] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil ];
        NSDictionary  *dataDict= [ persistanceDataObj getEntitySchemaForGinvenEntityIs:parameterDict ];
        id datatoserialize=[ dataDict objectForKey:VIEWS_KEY ];
        NSLog([ NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:datatoserialize options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil ])
    ;
        NSLog(@" entitySchemaForEntityId:%@",dataDict );
       // [[ NSNotificationQueue defaultQueue ]  enqueueNotification:[ NSNotification notificationWithName:ENTITYSCHEMANOTIFICATION object:nil userInfo:@{ USER_INFO:dataDict }] postingStyle:NSPostWhenIdle ];
        // sent view data to view controller



    }
```

Comment: Your first `NSLog` has no format string, hence the warning.

Comment: ... which means it will produce rubbish if the string contains a percent character and will likely crash if it contains %s or %@.

Answer (score 1):

Your `NSLog` is missing a format specifier. Use this instead:

`NSLog(@"%@",[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:datatoserialize options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil])
    ;`

Answer (score 0):

For your code `NSLog([ NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:datatoserialize options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil ])`, `NSLog` actually prints a string and needs a string format as input.

The function `dataWithJSONObject:options:error:` returns `NSData` and Not `NSString`, hence the warning.

You may try this instead `NSLog(@"%@",[ NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:datatoserialize options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil]);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your

```
NSLog([ NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:datatoserialize options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil ])
    ;
```

with the following one

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:datatoserialize options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil]);
```